# SELECT from multiple tables and display into table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I'm new with all this.

This is my original problem,
I have two tables called `order` and `order_items`

```
order_id--pupil_id --date_bought--total_price

1  ----1001---- 2013-03-07 23:35:49 - 1.00
```

and

```
order_id-- product_name

1 ------ product1

1 ------ product2
```

I want to display date bought and total price. It will be some sort of join statement with the products that have been bought with the most recent order_id which would be selected by pupil id which would be order by desc maybe in the statement.

I'm unsure on how to piece it together. Any ideas or clues on how to achieve this?

---

I have got this at the moment that Steve Chambers made me:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM `order` o
JOIN `order_items` oi
ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
ORDER BY o.order_id DESC");

$query_assoc = mysql_fetch_array($query);

echo $query_assoc['product_name'];

echo $query_assoc['date_bought'];

echo $query_assoc['total_price'];
```

This is a test to see if it works it does display the last order id row that is associated with the pupil id, but how do I retrieve all rows and place them into a table?

Comment: try with an `INNER JOIN`and `group by order_id`

Answer (score 0):

You're actually asking two questions here:

1. I want to display date bought and total price ....
2. how do i retrieve all rows and place them into a table

To get a collective price, you can either do it from the database by joining the tables together, you've already done that but to get a sum to make the total price you need to group the items together.  You'll need a query like:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.pupil_id, o.date_bought, SUM(o.total_price) AS total_price FROM order o
LEFT JOIN order_items oi
  ON oi.order_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY o.order_id
```

If you want to put the list of results in a table you will need to loop though the result set you have and write that out within an HTML table.